# How to import subset from MS Access based on condition criteria

Tags: python, dataframe, ms-access

I'm trying to use Python to create a dataframe which consists of certain rows (based on condition criteria) extracted from an MS Access table.
I can't seem to get the condition to work.
The MS Access table has column names such as Date, Course, Horse etc.

I want to, for example, get all the rows with `Date = "01-Dec-2021"` and `Course = "Kempton"`.
I have managed to get the following code working with one criterion:

```
import pyodbc

connStr = (r"DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" r"DBQ=C:\Users\chris\Documents\UKHR\SFF_Cum\SFFCum_py.accdb;")
        
conn = pyodbc.connect(connStr)
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql = "select * FROM SFF_cumQ_O where Course = ?"
cursor.execute(sql, ["Kempton"])
#print(cursor.fetchone())
print(cursor.fetchall())

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Here is my import of the rows based on Date = "01-Dec-2021" and Course = "Kempton"

```
import pyodbc

connStr = (r"DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" r"DBQ=C:\Users\chris\Documents\UKHR\SFF_Cum\SFFCum_py.accdb;")
        
conn = pyodbc.connect(connStr)
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql = "select * FROM SFF_cumQ_O WHERE Date = '01-Dec-2021' and Course = 'Kempton'"

cursor.execute(sql)
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

However, when I try to import the rows based on Date = "01-Dec-2021" and Course = "Kempton" I run into this error :

```
"Exception has occurred: Error
('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')"
```

Comment: change to `crsr.execute("select FROM Racecard_no_A WHERE Date = '01-Apr-2021' and Course = 'Kempton'")`

Comment: Thanks Dean - I tried your code but still get same error.

Comment: Hello Dean, the select code appears to need the asterisk:  "select * FROM SFF_cumQ_O where Course = ?".   However, I still cannot get it to work with the two-field filter:  Date = '01-Apr-2021' and Course = 'Kempton'

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem: the criteria needed to be bracketed.
Final code looks like this:
Note the table name is not necessary with the field name. So SFF_cumQ_O.Course can just be Course.

```
import pyodbc

connStr = (r"DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" r"DBQ=C:\Users\chris\Documents\UKHR\SFF_Cum\SFFCum_py.accdb;")
        
conn = pyodbc.connect(connStr)
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql = "select * FROM SFF_cumQ_O WHERE ((SFF_cumQ_O.Course)='Kempton') AND ((SFF_cumQ_O.RaceDate)='01-Dec-21')"
#sql = "select * FROM SFF_cumQ_O WHERE Date = '01-Dec-21' and Course = ?"

#cursor.execute(sql, ["Kempton"])
cursor.execute(sql)
print(cursor.fetchall())

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```